# apache TinkerPop gremlin How to filter starting vertex from path result

Tags: python-3.x, gremlin, tinkerpop3

guys! I am new to gremlin and I need a help.

I want to understand if there a way to do aggregation on the full graph per node based on values in the neighbors properties?

**Example:**
I want to calculate mean amount of money spent by a "known" customers.

My graph structure is next:

Customer1 -- > Phone_Number < -- Customer2.

So i want to get, as result, next:

- Customer1 Mean(Neighbors.value('money'))
- Customer2 Mean(Neighbors.value('money'))
- ...

The neighbors for a customer(base node) is all other customers (except himself) connected to one(or more) phones associated to base node.
I understand how to exclude base node if I know ID, but is there a way to do calculations across the full graph automatically excluding "starting" nodes?
Like, ignore CustomerK if we start from CustomerK along the all path?

**Another small question**: Is there a way to filter vertex properties in path by starting vertex value? Like, ignore all customers that older than "age" of starting vertex

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your start vertex by using the step `as` and then the `neq` predicate.

like this:

```
g.V().hasLabel('Customer').as('V').
  project('name', 'mean').by('name').by(out().
    in().where(neq('V')).dedup().values('money').
    mean())
```

example: https://gremlify.com/as

For filter by properties you can do something similar to this: `where(gt('V')).by('age')`.

```
g.V().hasLabel('Customer').as('V').
  project('name', 'mean').by('name').
    by(coalesce(
        out().in().where(neq('V')).where(gt('V')).
          by('age').
        dedup().values('money').mean(),
        constant('no values')
      ))
```